# Azure functions secured with Azure AD B2C returns unauthorized when using B2C tenant domain

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

Given an azure function secured via AAD B2C with https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/MyTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/signinsingunp as issuer url, I can successfully authenticate a b2c user via msal.js app, 
where as if I try to update issuer url to my b2ctenant domain login url (because of this advise [redirect URLs to b2clogin.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin)) and update authority in msal.js app to match domain(myapp.b2clogin.com/tfp/MyTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/signinsingunp), I am receiving 401 for same azure function, any advise will be appreciated.

Below are detailed setup details,

- Azure AD B2C Tenant

  - Domain Name: MyTenantName.onmicrosoft.com

    - Applications:

      - ApplicationA-Api

        - WebApp/API : Yes
        - Allow Implicit Flow : Yes
        - Reply Url : https://myazurefunsapi.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
        - App ID : https://MyTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/ApplicationA-Api
        - Published Scopes : read, user_impersonation
        - API Access : Access User Profile
      - ApplicationB-Portal

        - WebApp/API : Yes
        - Allow Implicit Flow : Yes
        - Reply Url : https://myportal.domain.com
        - App ID : https://MyTenantName.onmicrosoft.com/ApplicationB-Portal
        - Published Scopes : user_impersonation
        - API Access : ApplicationA-Api (read, access this app on behalf of signed in user), Access User Profile (offline_access, openid)
    - User Flows

      - SignupSignIn

        - Application : ApplicationA-Api
        - Reply Url : https://myazurefunsapi.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
        - Select Domain :

          - MyTenantName.b2clogin.com
          - login.microsoftonline.com
- Azure Functions

  - Authentication/Authorization

    - App Service Authentication : On
    - Action to take when not authenticated : Login with Azure AD
    - Authentication providers :

      - Azure AAD :
      - Management Mode : Advanced
      - client id : B2C-ApplicationA-ApplicationID
      - issuer url : login.microsoftonline.com/......./opendid......
- Static Website

  - b2c integration done by [msal.js](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp) (v0.2.4)
  - clientID : B2C-ApplicationB-ApplicationID
  - authority : https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/b2ctenantname.onmicrosoft.com/signinsingunp
  - b2cscopes : ApplicationA-Api-read

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of account you are using for?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron : Sorry, I can't understand your question. Can you pls elaborate.

Comment: Sure,I asked you what kind of user email you have used there as there are personal and work email and its mattered in b2c account.

Comment: as a test user, its an personal gmail account. At the moment in azure b2c tenant user flow policies > mysignupsignin-identity providers > Local Account Email sign up is enabled.

Comment: official [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-b2c-overview) outlines how to setup/consume msal.js

For some reason, the changes/updates are **not** immediate, it took me ~6-8 hours to work correctly !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found a solution to this...

It took a lot of scouring but **it's down to this [issue raised on GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/435)**

Essentially, I changed the authority when setting up my `UserAgentApplication` to use the new b2clogin.com domain that someone else mentioned.
Although this didn't work immediately, I received the same error you mentioned in the comments, so I had to set `validateAuthority: false` on my config.

I've included an example below on how I've set mine up. My ClientID is the same in Azure as it is in MSAL.js

```js
var msalConfig = {
      auth: {
        clientId: "xxxx",
        authority: "https://xxxx.b2clogin.com/tfp/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_xxxx", 
        webApi: 'https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net',
        b2cScopes: this.appConfig.b2cScopes,
        validateAuthority: false
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true
      }
    };
this.clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Charile.H : thx, I followed official documentation, which outlines similar [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-b2c-overview).
however, point to note, for some reason - the changes are **not** immediate !

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is changing Issuer URL (you wrote as Issuer URL but that must be .well-known config URL) to match with b2clogin.com domain.

From above I see your OpenID config URL  at Azure functions is

> login.microsoftonline.com/......./opendid......

But It should match with .well-known configuration of the static website of your b2clogin domain. It should be like

> https://tenantname.b2clogin.com/tfp/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Policy/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: I tried 
``1)  when I update my azure function with tenantname.b2clogin.com/tfp... I can get an auth token, but when I invoke function still 401.  Static website & func application are registered in same azure ad b2c domain``
2) updating static website index.html b2c authority property to https://<your-tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/tfp/<your-tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin1 => this results in ``endpoints_resolution_error:Endpoints cannot be resolved``